# How to make dropdown list(select tag) with one option drop down in IE11?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple select tag with `size="1"`, that is dynamically populated with options sometimes there is only one option. My issue is that when there is only one option in the dropdown list IE 11 does not dropdown the list and also the arrow disappears. Is there any way to force the IE 11 behavior to be the same as Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify a 'default' value like so:

```
<select>
    <option disabled selected style="display:none">Display Name</option>
    <?php echo $dropdown_list; ?>
</select>
```

The option's `disabled` attribute makes the option not allowed to be selected.

`selected` sets the option as the default selected value

`display:none` makes sure that the option itself doesn't show up in the dropdown.

So if you only have 1 option in the `$dropdown_list`, this will show up in the dropdown.

You will not, however, be able to **style** options to show up the same in all browsers.